# android camera menu

Tags: android

How to achieve a menu similar to the one in the image? I have a camera preview and would like to manipulate some of the colors using a seek bar. How can I display such a menu with transparent background and what is the name of that kind of menu?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with help of context menu 
may be this tutorial will help u out to built the  this type pf menu 
but in case of context menu there is a long click 
check them out these are some of the examples of context menu

http://www.anddev.org/creating_a_contextmenu_on_a_listview-t2438.html

http://coderzheaven.com/2011/03/context-menu-in-android/

Comment: Is it possible to add views such as TextView or SeekBar to the context menu or just text?